# Parallax with HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, parallax

I am working on a parallax site that has a full size background image at the top of the page. It currently is using fixed positioned containers that are adjusted using jquery on scroll events.

Heres an example

CSS

```
#bg{
      z-index: -5;
      positioned: fixed;
      width: 100%
      height: auto;
   }

#skyline{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }
```

MARKUP

```
<div id="bg">
  <img id="skyline" src="skyline.jpg" alt="Skyline"/>
</div>
```

I am then using jQuery to adjust the top position when a scroll event is triggered. The results work but it is very choppy. I have tried lowering the quality / file size of the image but from the research I have done it looks like its because of the area the background covers (The larger the redraw the choppier it will be)

From the research I have been doing it looks like using an HTML 5 canvas will help this issue. I am wondering if anyone can suggest how to acheive a full size background that resizes with the window using HTML5 Canvas.

Any help would be great

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I think I understand your confusion. So

```
dx = 0
dy = 0
dWidth = window.innerWidth // use your favorite method for obtaining the width/height
...
```

Then all you have to do is vary the source coordinates on every frame, while sWidth and sHeight would be equal to dWidth and dHeight (this is the size of the slice, you want it to match your screen).

I hope this helps

---

Check out the [documentation of canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images). I think it is explained well.

Look at example 3, where you can specify offsets for the image:

```
drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
```

How large is the image you are using, exactly? If you are moving around a 3mb pic I can imagine it'd be choppy on most machines.

Also, for animations Chrome/Chromium behaves much better, that is why I use it for development, but do my general browsing in Firefox.

Comment: I have read over the documentation and got the image to display but its not resizing correctly and its zoomed in on the image for some reason. Can I make it resize the image to the canvas size? (which should be the width of the window) .......The image is only about 300kb but it still is sluggish even on my brand new macbook pro retina running a quad core I7.

Comment: Are you sure you read carefully enough :) "The first four parameters define the location and size of the slice on the source image. The last four parameters define the position and size on the destination canvas."

Comment: I will give this a try when I am back home and post the results.....much appreciated my friend